# hotels whose average room price is higher than the average price of all the rooms in all the hotels

Tags: sql

I have this database of hotel, room, booking and guest 
I need to get the average price of only the hotels whose average price is higher than the average price of all the rooms in all the hotels.
Here is what my data looks like

```
Hotel (hotelNo,hotelName,hotelAddress)
Room (hotelNo,roomNo,type,price)
Guest (guestNo,guestName,guestAddress)
Booking (hotelNo,guestNo,dateFrom,dateTo,roomNo)
```

here is my query for that

```
 SELECT (
  SELECT hotelName
  from hotel
  where hotel.hotelNo = room.hotelNo
 ) AS "Hotel Name",
 AVG(price) t
 FROM room 
 where t<(SELECT AVG(price)from room)
  Group by hotelNo
```

Comment: What is the question? If your query's failing, how does it fail?

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like:

```
select hotelName
from hotel
where hotelNo in ( 
  select hotelNo 
  from Room
  group by hotelNo
  having avg( price ) > select avg( price ) from Room 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build up your query using TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design.

#### Average cost of rooms at each hotel

```
SELECT HotelNo, AVG(Price) AS AvgPrice
  FROM Room
 GROUP BY HotelNo;
```

#### Average cost of rooms at all hotels

```
SELECT AVG(Price) AS AvgPrice
  FROM Room;
```

#### Hotels where the average cost of a room is greater than overall average cost of a room

```
SELECT HotelNo
  FROM Room
 GROUP BY HotelNo
HAVING AVG(Price) > (SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Room)
```

#### Details for the hotels ...

```
SELECT HotelNo, HotelName, HotelAddress
  FROM Hotel AS H
  JOIN (SELECT HotelNo
          FROM Room
         GROUP BY HotelNo
        HAVING AVG(Price) > (SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Room)
       ) AS E
    ON H.HotelNo = E.HotelNo
```

There are other ways of writing that last query.

It's TDQD because you can test each stage to ensure you get the expected results, building up confidence that the final complex query is correct.  And if there's a problem, you have less to undo if you've developed the query step-wise.